# Custom JSON renderer in AEM/Sling

Tags: json, jsp, aem, sling

I've been playing around with this for a while now, and I think, I've - almost - cracked it, but I am still not fully satisfied with my solution.

So, what I want to do, is having a piece of content, a list of items, which would have two views: The standard HTML one, so people can view and edit it; and then a JSON endpoint for other services to consume.

First I thought it's a simple matter of creating two JSP scripts to render the content:

- /apps/my-stuff/components/list-page/html.jsp
- /apps/my-stuff/components/list-page/json.jsp

However the Apache Sling `DefaultServlet` seems to be rather ignorant of the `json.jsp` script.

As a second attempt, I created another script, in `/apps/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/json.jsp` which will be actually called, and renders the page, as I expected. However there are a couple of worries/questions regarding this:

- First of all, why is this being honoured by the system, and not the one in the more specific place?
- The documentation states, that to find the appropriate renderer, first `sling:resourceType` will be inspected, then `sling:resourceSuperType` and then, only as a fallback will `jcr:PrimaryType` checked. However I think this is rather: `jcr:PrimaryType`, then the `DefaultServlet`, and then all the other things.
- Most worryingly however, I have to admit, this is rather generic, so it'll break all the contnet with `jcr:PrmaryType = Page`, so that could have some side-effects.

A solution could be creating a new type: `ListPage extends Page`; and then create a renderer for that in `/apps/foundation...`. However I have this bad feeling, that might introduce other problems.

So my question is two fold: What is the proper way of doing this, and/or what am I missing from the way the **URL -> script** resolution is working in AEM/Sling. (Because it seems to be slightly different that described [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html) and [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aTPp4Vt8CYo/U9ZLx4C4X5I/AAAAAAAAAao/BmrEJFdyF80/s1600/image.img.png).)

(Obviously I am trying to keep the default JSON renderer for other pages, as that might be needed for other things in the page. I am not even sure, changing this one page won't break the UI for this particular page...)

Answer (score 0):

> However the Apache Sling DefaultServlet seems to be rather ignorant of the json.jsp script.

Have you tried renaming your JSP like so: "list-page.json.jsp"?

If you're using AEM 6.3, you should look at [Sling model Exporters](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#exporter-framework-since-130). They allow you to automatically register a servlet against your Sling Model (that you can create to model your list content). That servlet can generate a JSON representation of the model for you using Jackson.

If you're not using AEM 6.3, I would suggest you create a servlet registered against your resource type and use an additional selector.

```
@SlingServlet(
   selectors = "json",
   resourceType = "my-stuff/components/list-page",
   methods = "GET")
```

More information on Sling Servlets can be found [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html).